# Do we need a canonical question about C++ initialization?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Recently, these two questions:

- [What is the difference, if any, between {x} and '= {x}' initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28569030/3920237)
- [Are there any differences between these two lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28651855/3920237)

have made me wonder if we need a solid canonical duplicate for [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) initialization. The reason why I picked these two particular questions is because:

- they demonstrate little to no research effort, but they are highly upvoted, indicating interest
- they are recent
- the questions seem basic but the answers can be complex. On the other hand, the question implies a supposed significant difference between two forms of syntax, when in fact they are very similar.

The broad and general nature of these questions also make it hard to mark them as duplicates, although I'm certain that they exist in some form or the other. I'm looking for something like [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c), whenever somebody asks about `sizeof` or confuses arrays and pointers.

Some examples of good resources would be:

- [Herb Sutter's blog](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/), which talks about all forms of initialization
- [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), which pulls information directly from the Standard, but makes it human-readable and organizes them neatly into separate pages

Because the nature of such a canonical question is likely to be too broad, as I believe the two linked questions are, I suggest a condensed version of cppreference's approach, which succinctly covers most cases, like [T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28569191/3920237). The benefit of having the information in one place is that contemporary knowledge, like defects and the subtle differences between language standards, can be found in one place. It would also reduce the need to copy/paste fervently from the almighty ISO standard, which I feel most of the time spent in an answer is spent copy editing.

Is such a question viable or would it be too broad?

Comment: If someone writes it all down (and mind differences between standards) in a concise, correct and complete way, they will get my vote. Trouble is, it's quite complex, probably best compared to the canonical question for [operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading), which does not seem to be complete and up-to-date (any more?)....

Comment: We've had a [tag:c++-faq] canonical question on initialization before, but it probably needs to be updated for C++11 list-initialization

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21825933/103167

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13461027/103167

Comment: The only reason I managed to get that answer that short is because the question is "what's the difference" rather than "what does it do". If I had to explain what list-initialization actually does, that would take quite a bit of space.

Answer (score 4):

We technically already have one [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat). We also have the related question about [`new` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new).

I don't see what a newer question would do but we could probably edit the first one to be more up to date with the C++11 rules.

Ideally speaking a title change to "What are the different types of C++ initialisation?" would do the canonical question some wonders, along with an answer that actually answers the title question in a human readable form.

Comment: Actually,  there's a [newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233148/meaning-of-default-initialization-changed-in-c11) available but it only talks about default initialization.

Comment: That question only covers the no-or-empty initializer cases though.

Comment: I set the linked one to protected. I think this should be done with all FAQ questions to avoid clutter.

Answer (score -6):

I don't think we need a canonical duplicate. We need people to *read their C++ books*. We do not need Stack Overflow to become a C++ book.

Minimal understanding and prior research are both expected and required here, and this is one of those times when it's a shame the associated close-vote reason was removed.

As for [the closest existing FAQ question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1613341/560648), I don't see that helping the authors of the complained-about questions in the slightest, to be honest.

Comment: Both a book and SO can cover the same topic. A book can provide a rough broad picture with few bright sharp spots -- a coherent picture in context -- shallow answers to questions an author thinks should be answered with a small number of questions discussed in depth. SO can highlight and put into focus any spot from different angles but it worse at zooming out and looking at forest behind the trees -- a fragmented view -- real questions by and for the people with very different answers that can be ranked by the community. If there is a bug in the implementation; the question is not too trivial

Comment: Empirical evidence suggests that people do not read their C++ books.  Witness many of the questions on SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Right, because they've been trained that they can get their crap answered here rather than studying! We can change that.

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit as people should read the basics first before coming to SO. A lot of question are closed because they are to basic. Even worst when people make books out of SO questions that nobody would read then like [this iText one](https://leanpub.com/itext_so/)

Comment: Basic is one thing but clear lack of prior research is another. The two sort of go hand in hand, I guess. Such a position is usually brushed aside as "elitist" but that's a derogatory way to describe a position which _actually_ amounts to "we are not here to teach everyone everything from scratch, repeatedly".

Comment: So since the C++ standard is available as a book, we can close absolutely every question that could be answered by reading the standard?

Comment: @Voo: That's perhaps the most outstanding strawman argument I've seen all year so far.

Comment: If anything it's reductio ad absurdum. But you missed the actual point: which book do you want to require people to have read to decide what constitutes a good question? What if someone read a book about c++03 And then wants to know about changes that came in c++11? And that's apart from the fact that the whole thing is against the whole premise of SO.

Comment: @Voo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list Requiring a minimal understanding is absolutely _not_ "against the whole premise of SO", not at all, and this has been documented many many times.

Comment: @Voo That's not a problem if someone "wants to know" something, as long as they do their research, instead of expecting others to do this for them. I imagine that "read their books" in this post is figurative speech for "try to put some effort first".

Comment: @Lightness There was a very clear blogpost by Joel Spolsky (I think that) clearly said that there weren't any too easy questions for SO and that "you can google the answer" wasn't a good reason to not have it on SO. Which is pretty much the exact opposite of "only allow questions that wouldn't come up if you had read a book and did prior research".

Comment: @Voo: You're not understanding me. And, I repeat, the requirement for a prior minimal understanding is well documented. I'm not going to go dig it out for you; there are many posts about it on meta. Since you're being lazy, you could simply hover over the downvote button and spot that _questions require research effort_. There is a [thin] difference between a beginner question and a question that has had literally no research effort applied. And, if you have a beginner question, the research effort you should apply is to _read the relevant chapter in your book_. We are _not_ here to teach.

Comment: "Since you're being lazy" I'm lazy for not finding proof for some claims you make? Hilarious. Anyhow [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) the official guidelines for what questions can be asked on SO. If you'd like to point out where in the *official* guidelines it says you can't ask simple questions you could easily find with a google search (and again the standard is one search away, so this is a crappy rule in itself anyhow). That page deals with all the important things: No duplicates, reasonably scoped, has a definite answer,.. nothing on complexity.

Comment: Furthermore [search, and research](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says: "Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere *on the site*, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.". You notice how it doesn't refer to research on *other* sites? QED.

Comment: @Voo: And now you're just not listening. Oh well.

Comment: Ah ad hominem now, we really do try to get through all fallacies today. But no I *am* listening, just disagreeing with your claims and not finding anything that actually supports your view. Research effort applies only to *the site* you are on (certainly duplicate questions help nobody), so books and google are out. There's nothing about "minimal understanding" in the FAQ about asking questions. If I'm missing something just show me the supporting documentation for it.

Comment: @Voo: Uh, no. An _ad hominem_ argument is an _argument_ purportedly supported only by insults. I did not employ an _ad hominem_, because I wasn't trying to support my argument. I was just making an observation. Don't worry, though, because that's a very common misconception: people overuse the phrase "ad hominem" all the time and I've become rather accustomed to that. Anyway, back to the point, I've already presented my arguments and you've ignored all of them. My burden of proof is satisfied and your rejection of it is your own responsibility. :) Good day.

Comment: So you either don't consider "you're not listening" an insult or you just decided to flee into observations instead of countering my arguments - oh well. But yes this is not going anywhere considering that the proof you've shown so far was "there are many posts about it on meta" without a single link and pointing out the (misunderstood as shown by my quote from the guidelines) tooltip "questions require research effort". In any case the community also seems to agree with me, both with the vote count here and on the linked questions.

Comment: @Voo: I didn't say it wasn't an insult. I said it wasn't an argument formed from an insult. And clearly, it's accurate!